# How can I refactor the binary code sent from the client to the server in Dart?

Tags: dart, sockets, tcp, socket.io, binary

In this code, I convert the data file into binary and send it to the server:
code Client:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  final socket = await Socket.connect('localhost', 8000);
  print('Connected to server');

  final file = File(
      'D:\\Flutter\\rock_paper_scissors\\assets\\images\\sang.txt'); // مسیر فایلی که می خواهید داده ها را از آن خوانده و به سرور ارسال کنید
  final stream = file.openRead();

  stream.listen((data) {
    print('Read data from file: ${String.fromCharCodes(data)}');
    socket.write(data); // ارسال داده ها به سرور
  });

  socket.done.then((_) {
    print('Disconnected from server');
  });
}
```

In this code. I convert the binary code sent from the client side into a string, but this operation is not performed correctly
code Server:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() async {
  final server = await ServerSocket.bind('localhost', 8000);
  print('Server started on port ${server.port}');

  await for (Socket client in server) {
    handleClient(client);
  }
}

void handleClient(Socket client) async {
  print(
      'Client connected from: ${client.remoteAddress.address}:${client.remotePort}');
  final file = File('D:\\UI\\text.txt');
  final sink = file.openWrite();

  await client
      .listen((data) async {
        Uint8List binaryData = Uint8List.fromList(data);
        String stringData = String.fromCharCodes(binaryData);

        print('Received data: $stringData');

        sink.write(data);
      })
      .asFuture()
      .then((_) {
        sink.close();
        client.close();
        print('Client disconnected');
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `openRead` you get a stream of bytes, without any encoding. Your `.txt` file might contain encoded bytes eg UTF-8. You might want to try decoding bytes to text before reading, eg from File doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html:

```
Stream<String> lines = file.openRead()
    .transform(utf8.decoder)       // Decode bytes to UTF-8.
    .transform(LineSplitter());
```

Comment: Can you tell me where in the code I should use it?